# SGML in css "content"

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to output SGML characters with a css `:before { content:"" }` statement?

This does not work:

```
span:before { content:"&radic;" }
```

Escaping doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean SGML/HTML entities?

No, the `content` property doesn't accept markup; in this case, you need to use the actual Unicode character √, or its corresponding escape sequence instead:

```
span:before { content:"\221A" }
```

Comment: The answer is correct and practical. But for completeness: it is possible to use `&radic;` inside a `style` element in an XHTML document served with an XHTML doctype. Not because that would make `&radic;` correct in CSS but because XHTML parses `style` elements so that entity references are recognized (and interpreted, replacing them by their meanings, before passing the data to the CSS interpreter part of a browser).